# REST webservice that consumes XML

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest

I am learning REST webservice and confused about some concepts.
I want to create a RESTful webservice that consumes an XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<emp:EmployeeEntry xmlns:emp="http://www.employee/entry">
  <emp:number>12345</emp:number>
  <emp:name>George</emp:name>
  <emp:date>2015-04-03</emp:date>
  <emp:address>
    <emp:city>Paris</emp:city>
    <emp:street>East 35</emp:street>
  </emp:address>
</emp:EmployeeEntry>
```

So, If I want to create a restful webservice that consumes this XML, How would be the signature of my method?

```
    public creatEmp(XML xml);
```

Should it be like this? 
(Because I saw some examples of methods that consume XML, but they are taking parameter as main entiry object eg; Employee I don't understand how a method that consumes XML accepts and Entity object as parameter)

Also, If the method is given XML as parameter, do I have to implement parsing logic in the method then create Employee object from that and the start the main create logic?

I have some knowledge gaps, please suggest me some examples or some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify your input parameter as XML string, for example JAX-RS automatically makes the  conversion for you.

See the example below:

```
@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeService {
    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName("Test Employee");
        return emp;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response createEmployee(Employee emp) {
        // Write your code here to save the employee
    }
}
```

You can check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs.htm) for more information.